# Amazon MWS C# XSD class generation

Tags: c#, xsd, amazon-mws

I'm working on a project to upload products to Amazon using MWS in C#.  I have their class libraries, and have attempted to generate classes from the XSD files like I have for other similar projects.  However, running xsd.exe to generate the classes throws errors.  Such as:

```
Error generating classes for schema 'amzn-envelope'. - Schema with targetNamespace='' has invalid syntax.  The simpleType 'BluRayRegionType' has already been declared. Line 130, position 3.
```

The xsd files have a lot of includes and do have multiple references.  Am I missing a standard workaround/solution?  Or are amazons XSD files just not usable to generate classes?  If they aren't useable, what can I do instead to accomplish this?

EDIT:

Unfortunately the XSDs are gated behind a login on Amazon Seller Central that requires a paying seller account so I cant link them.

This question: [Is there a (C#) library that will create feeds for Amazon Marketplace Web Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694649/is-there-a-c-library-that-will-create-feeds-for-amazon-marketplace-web-servic)
is similar and also unresolved.

Comment: This XSD nothing but WSDL?

Comment: @Amit I'm not sure what you mean by that

Comment: What XSD files are you talking about? I downloaded the C# client library from https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/bde/feeds/v20090901/cSharp.html/186-8418274-8248907, there are no XSD files in there at all.

Comment: can you link to the XSD files are you using?

Comment: I edited my question.  I cant link the XSD files since they are behind a login with a seller account on amazon.  I was hoping someone would have recent experience and a work-around for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use xsd.exe or xsd2code utility to convert xsd files into C# classes. xsd2code has Visual studio plugin too.